# how to configure separate port numbers for admin and search URLs

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 4.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.
Running it with jetty on port 8983 per default configuration.

Is there a way to configure Solr to expose the admin UI on :8983 and the search API (/select&q=...) on a different port (:80) ?

I would like to keep them separate for security reasons, keeping the 8983 behind the firewall while opening the 80 to internet traffic. If you have suggestions for this or a different approach...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put Apache in front of Solr and use reverse proxy to map paths at port 80 to /select. The /admin path would not be mapped. Internal users could go directly to Solr.

But...exposing Solr directly to Internet traffic is a bad idea. It isn't designed for that. Write a front end that uses Solr and send the Internet traffic to that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to run the admin and search components on separate ports, as they are both part of one service. However, by following the examples outlined in the [SolrSecurity - Common Servlet Container Example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Common_servlet_container_example), you can setup basic authentication to restrict access to the `/admin` path, and implement the Jetty specific realm setup instructions to setup the users who have access.

Comment: thank you Paige, will probably add this to the proxy based approach